# For loop not working as expected inside python flask

Tags: python, flask

HI i have a small python script which untars a list of files present in a folder.Below is the script.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/untarJson')

def untarJson():

    outdir="C:\\Users\\esrilka\\Documents\\Tar Files\\Untar"
    inputfilefolder="C:\\Users\\esrilka\\Documents\\Tar Files\\New tar files\\"  
    jsonfiles=[]  
    for filenames in os.listdir(inputfilefolder):
        if filenames.endswith(".tar.gz"):       
            head,tail= os.path.split(filenames)
            basename=os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(tail)[0])[0]

            t = tarfile.open(os.path.join(inputfilefolder,filenames), 'r')
            for member in t.getmembers():

                if "autodiscovery/report.json" in member.name:
                    with open(os.path.join(outdir,basename + '.json' ), 'wb') as f:

                        f.write(t.extractfile('autodiscovery/report.json').read())





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It works fine without flask and in the folder i have four tar files and all 4 files are untarred.

But when i use flask only one file is untarred and the only one file name is displayed.

how can i untar all files inside a folder and also return the name of the files(i.,. only short names and not with full path)

Comment: What you meant by only one file name is displayed ? I dont see any code related to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the below code works for you, I have changed only little bit to your original code and it works without any issues. All the available tar.gz files are untared and file names gets displayed after request completes,

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import tarfile
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/untarJson')
def untarJson():
    outdir = "C:\\tests\\untared"
    inputfilefolder = "C:\\tests"
    jsonfiles = []
    for filenames in os.listdir(inputfilefolder):
        if filenames.endswith(".tar.gz"):
            head, tail = os.path.split(filenames)
            basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(tail)[0])[0]

            t = tarfile.open(os.path.join(inputfilefolder, filenames), 'r')
            for member in t.getmembers():

                if "autodiscovery/report.json" in member.name:
                    with open(os.path.join(outdir, basename + '.json'), 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(t.extractfile('autodiscovery/report.json').read())
                        jsonfiles.append(os.path.join(outdir, basename + '.json'))
    return jsonify(jsonfiles), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After request completed, something like below will be returned (output will be different in your case),
`[
"C:\tests\untared\autodiscovery1.json",
"C:\tests\untared\autodiscovery2.json",
"C:\tests\untared\autodiscovery3.json"
]`